# Filtering a list of citizens

Tags: python

I have a filter method that receives a list composed of dictionaries. You must discard dictionaries that have their `handle` or their `citizen_number` elements off the filtered result as well as concatenate any lists inside that dictionary. In addition to that, in case an element on that main list is a `None`it should be skipped and all the `None` dictionary elements should be replaced by a zero. This is the solution that I have come up with to do so

```
def citizens(citizen_list):
    filtered_list = []
    try:
        for citizen in citizen_list:
            if citizen:
                for item in citizen:
                    if not item:
                        citizen[item] = 0
                if (citizen['handle'] == 0 or citizen['citizen_number'] == 0):
                    continue
                if (citizen['organizations'] is not None):
                    citizen['organizations'] = ', '.join(
                        org['sid'] for org in citizen['organizations'])
                else:
                    citizen['organizations'] = 0
                for item in citizen:
                    if(type(citizen[item]) is list):
                        citizen[item] = ', '.join(citizen[item])
                filtered_list.append(citizen)
        return(filtered_list)
    except Exception:
        print(citizen)
        raise
```

Note that the list concatenation for the `organizations`field must be done before the general one and in that particular way. I feel this code just looks awfully hacked together, how can I make this better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't speak to the specifics of the problem, since I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but the general idea seems to be:

1. Filter `citizen_list` based on some critiera
2. Apply some transformation to each citizen in `citizen_list`

To make that clearer, we can rewrite the code this way:

```
def _transform_citizen(citizen):
    # ???

def _is_valid_citizen(citizen):
    return citizen['handle'] and citizen['citizen_number']

def citizens(citizen_list):
    return [
        _transform_citizen(citizen)
        for citizen in citizen_list
        if _is_valid_citizen(citizen)
    ]
```

This has several benefits. It will reduce multiple layers of indentation. It will give you two functions with focused criteria. And it will make it clear that `citizens()` is doing just a filter and a transformation on the input list.